Expand out values in rows to distribute values
I have a series of values in Excel.
The top row is a base number. The second row is how many values in each number in the series. The third row is the total value of that number in the series.

Note that in my example the numbers in the third row add to 42 (a complete fluke!).
I want to expand those numbers out like this:

The series number is the base plus the sequence from 1 to the number in the second row. Then the value is the value number divided by the number in the current sequence.
Note that the final row adds to the same as the input row. I'm distributing those numbers evenly.
The real application here is to expand out the values in a budget done monthly by the number of days in the month and distribute the numbers by day. I then intend to group by weeks.
I'm struggling to get even the most basic expansion to work:
=HSTACK(BYCOL(R8C3:R8C5,LAMBDA(n,SEQUENCE(n,1))))

I'd love to get pointed in the right direction.

I don't know who voted to close based on this not being about programming. It's quite well established that Excel is a functional programming tool.

Not sure whether this is what you are asking for, however, I came up with this using TOROW()+SEQUENCE()+XLOOKUP()


• Formula used in cell A6
=LET(
     α, A2:C2,
     δ, SEQUENCE(MAX(α)),
     VSTACK(TOROW(IF(δ<=α,A1:C1+δ,NA()),2,1),
     TOROW(IF(δ<=α,A3:C3/XLOOKUP(A1:C1,A1:C1,α),NA()),2,1)))


Unclubbed Version:


• Formula used in cell A6
=LET(α, A2:C2, δ, SEQUENCE(MAX(α)), TOROW(IF(δ<=α,A1:C1+δ,NA()),2,1))


• Formula used in cell A7
=LET(α, A2:C2, δ, SEQUENCE(MAX(α)), TOROW(IF(δ<=α,A3:C3/XLOOKUP(A1:C1,A1:C1,α),NA()),2,1))


Instead of using IF() we can use IFS() as well in the formulas above.

Solution is based on my other answer to How to convert a column of age counts into a set useful for statistics?

A shorter version, since these numbers we can use the following as well and no IF() or IFS() needed:
=LET(α, A2:C2, δ, SEQUENCE(MAX(α)), TOROW(A1:C1+δ/(δ<=α),2,1))


And
=LET(α, A2:C2, Σ, A1:C1, TOROW((A3:C3/XLOOKUP(Σ,Σ,α))/(SEQUENCE(MAX(α))<=α),2,1))



That looks pretty good. Ideally it'd be split out into two formulas. One for each output row. The 1001, 1002, etc, are my header rows, and then the values are repeated for multiple input rows.

Yes i have clubbed them together using VSTACK(). unlcubbing shown. please check !

I'm not having any joy "unclubbing" them.

Have you checked the unclubbed version. it expands and contracts as per inputs.

Perfect, thank you. I now have =LET(headers,R31C3:R31C5,repeats,R32C3:R32C5,sequence,SEQUENCE(MAX(repeats)),TOROW(IF(sequence<=repeats,headers+sequence,NA()),2,1)) and =LET(headers,R31C3:R31C5,repeats,R32C3:R32C5,values,R33C3:R33C5,sequence,SEQUENCE(MAX(repeats)),TOROW(IF(sequence<=repeats,values/XLOOKUP(headers,headers,repeats),NA()),2,1)).

I can't stand working in A1, but most people seem to prefer it. R1C1 is so much cleaner.
